# How do I make really large text in Smalltalk?

Tags: smalltalk, squeak

I'm trying to make a large text banner in Squeak Smalltalk, with the following code:

```
t := TextMorph new.
t string: 'You win!' fontName: 'BitstreamVeraSans' size: 400.
t extent: 600@100.
t center: Display center.
t openInWorld.
```

But the text size seems to max out at about 60. Am I using the wrong class? I don't need the text to be editable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two ways:

1. Add another font size: `(TextStyle named: #BitstreamVeraSans) addNewFontSize: 200` and use a regular text morph as before.
2. Use a "Truetype banner" which can be arbitrarily scaled: Either get one from the object catalog, or use `TTSampleStringMorph new initializeToStandAlone openInHand`. Look into the initializeToStandAlone method to make your own.

For a large heading I probably would use the

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because Squeak uses bitmap fonts as standard. The maximal size for BitstreamVeraSans included in the Squeak image seems to be 36.
So while you can scale the Morph, the text itself does not get any bigger.

In Pharo you can use TrueType fonts in a TextMorph like this:

```
|font textMorph text|
font := (TextFontReference toFont: (LogicalFont familyName: 'Cochin' pointSize: 99)).
text := 'You win!' asText addAttribute: font.
textMorph := TextMorph new.
textMorph contents: text.
textMorph openInWorld
```

Something similar might be possible in Squeak too. There is some TrueType support included.

Comment: That makes sense. So is there anyway that I could scale up the bitmap fonts? I'm happy if they are a bit pixellated.

Comment: I don't know. You could perhaps try to transform the TextMorph to an imageForm and then open this as Morph (`textMorph imageForm asMorph openInWorld`)? This is resizable in Pharo. But probably it's better to investigate how to use TrueType fonts.

Comment: @EricClack If you don't mind of pixellated, you could inquire Form>>magnifyBy:

Comment: OK this works... `f := t imageForm magnifyBy: 4. m := f asMorph openInWorld.`